# Why would logging of PHP errors stop?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, plesk

Using Plesk with Apache and Nginx together on Centos.

Errors were being logged perfectly on;

/var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/error_log

/var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log

I truncated the files by deleting and recreating them; now nothing is logged. File owner and the file permissions are all the same; but error logging has just stopped.

I check the other domains, they all perfectly work as supposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually web server logs are stored in `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/`.

Log files in `/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/` it's not a files but hardlinks to files in `/var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/`. Pay attention for same inode number 261064:

```
# ls -lia /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
261064 -rw-r--r--. 2 root root 2432 Jun  8 18:26 /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
# ls -lia /var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/error_log
261064 -rw-r--r--. 2 root root 2432 Jun  8 18:26 /var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/error_log
```

when I've remove this file I've remove hardlink:

```
# rm /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
rm: remove regular file `/var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log'? y
# ls -lia /var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/error_log
261064 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2432 Jun  8 18:26 /var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/error_log
```

When I've create it again it will has own inode number(276777):

```
# touch /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
# ls -lia /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
276777 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jun  8 18:33 /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
```

So to solve you issue you just need to remove file you have created and create hardlink to file in system/log:

```
# rm /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
# ln /var/www/vhosts/system/example.tld/logs/error_log /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
# ls -lia /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
261064 -rw-r--r--. 2 root root 2432 Jun  8 18:33 /var/www/vhosts/example.tld/logs/error_log
```

Answer (score 0):

the server probably still tries to write to the files you deleted. restart nginx and apache.

Comment: I already told in the question that I already recreated the files with full permissions. Plus, I guess even if the file hand't been existed; it should have created the log file itself. And btw, yes servers are already restarted.